# c++ How to Reading file in to dynamic array and accessing array elements

Tags: c++, file, pointers, dynamic-arrays

I'm learning how to use `fstream` with `dynamic array`, the program supposed to print out all the data in `txt file` and can do something like sorting, delete gender or calculate average grade. **But turned out code is all messy and arrays are hard to access.**

**This is the text file  use to practice.**
[image]

Code:

```
struct studentData{
   string branch;
   string name;
   char gender;
   double grade;
   int number;
   int total;
};


int main() {

    int line_count = 0;
    ifstream file_in;
    int couter = 0;
    file_in.open("student.txt");
    if(!file_in.good())
        {
            cout << "Eror, could not open the file." << endl;
            file_in.clear();
            return -1;
        }   
        line_count = openFileTest(file_in);
        file_in.clear();
        file_in.seekg(ios::beg);
        studentData* p_studentData = new studentData[line_count];

    loadStudentData(file_in, p_studentData,couter);
    displayStudentData(p_studentData, line_count,couter);

        delete [] p_studentData;

        file_in.close();

        return 0;
}


int openFileTest(ifstream& file_in)
{
    string temp;
    int linecount = 0;

    while(getline(file_in, temp))
    {
        linecount ++;
    }

    return linecount;

}

void loadStudentData(ifstream& file_in,studentData* p_studentData,int couter)
{

    int temp ;
    file_in >> p_studentData -> total ;
    temp = p_studentData->total;

    for(int i=0;i<temp;i++)
    {
    file_in >> p_studentData->branch >> p_studentData->number ;
        for(int k=0;k<p_studentData[i].number;k++)
        {
            file_in >> p_studentData[k].name  >> p_studentData[k].gender >> p_studentData[k].grade ;
        }   
        p_studentData++;
    }
    return;
}

void displayStudentData(studentData* p_studentData, int count_line,int couter)
{

        cout << p_studentData->total << endl;
        int temp = p_studentData->total ;
    for(int i=0;i<temp;i++)
    {
        cout << p_studentData[i].branch << "  " ;
        cout << p_studentData[i].number << endl;
        for(int j=0;j<p_studentData[i].number;j++)
        {
            cout << p_studentData[j].name << "  " << p_studentData[j].gender << "  " << p_studentData[j].grade << endl;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

The output I get is:

[image]

Comment: [To align output read up on `std::setw`.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw)

Comment: If your file format  is not yet fix, I recommend to use a json parser, e.g. https://github.com/nlohmann/json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you are not being careful to track where you are in the file. I don't know why arrays[] are so popular for these kinds of assignments when a vector would do, but notice that you are missing a level of abstraction:

your code: array of student
assignment: array of subject; each subject is an array of student

It is often very helpful to use types to keep track of this:

```
struct student
{
  // as above
};

struct subject
{
  string name;
  int number_of_students;
  student* students;
};

struct all_subjects
{
  int number_of_subjects;
  subject* subjects;
};
```

Using this, we can work on deciphering the file:

```
all_subjects load_all_subjects()
{
  ifstream f( ... );
  ...
  all_subjects all;
  f >> all.number_of_subjects;
  all.subjects = new subject[ all.number_of_subjects ];
  for (int n = 0; n < all.number_of_subjects; n++)
    load_one_subject( f, all.subjects[ n ] );
  return all_students;
}

void load_one_subject( std::ifstream& f, subject& one_subject )
{
  f >> one_subject.name;
  f >> one_subject.number_of_students;
  one_subject.students = new student[ one_subject.number_of_students ];
  for (int n = 0; n < one_subject.number_of_students; n++)
    load_one_student( f, one_subject.students[ n ] );
}
```

And so on. Good luck!

Comment: sorry but compiler return error message "cannot convert subject to subject* " at 
load_one_subject( f, all.subjects[ n ] );  am i missing something ?

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally made the argument a pointer instead of a direct reference. When programming, we must pay attention to the _type_ of a thing at all times.